# Extract specific directory from zipped archive to different directory using Windows CMD shell

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, zip

GitHub zip files normally contain a single directory in the zip. I want to unzip the contents of a zipped directory to a different directory as shown in Linux answer at: [How to extract only a specific folder from a zipped archive to a given directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115241)

eg `unzip <target-zip-file> '<folder-to-extract/*>' -d <destination-path>`

The command still extracts files to `destination-path\folder-to-extract`. How do I extract without creating `folder-to-extract`?

(The -j modifier discards all directories.)

Comment: Do you want to use [7ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/)? that's open-source. Then here is the command: `7z x -o"folder-path" "archive-file-name"`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo `x` will restore the folder tree stored in the zip underneath the given `-o` folder . Provided it is a flat dir to restore I suggest using `e` : ` e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)`